# How to control for population change when studying regional employment by sector?

Tags: econometrics, economics

I want to examine regional changes in employment by sector. However some regions have shrinking population and even when the economy is triving, it still shows that employment is falling, but obviously it is because the population declines in numbers. Employment rate grows, as it accounts for population change, but it applies to total employment, not sectoral employment.

I use the following to control for population, but I am not sure if this is the right approach.

The number of employed workers in sector A fell in 2017 by 2%. The number of people in employment age fell by 2.5%. The adjusted employment change in sector A is

-2% - (-2.5%) = 0.5%

Is this a good way to deal with the problem?